# case statement in index creation

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, ddl

How do i use a CASE statement when creating a UNIQUE INDEX?

My statement looks like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_unique_creation 
    ON junk ((CASE 
                WHEN nlevel(path) > 1 THEN (subpath(path, 0, -1), name) 
                ELSE (path, name) END)) 
WHERE my_col IS NULL;
```

This fails on the following line:

```
pq: column "" has pseudo-type record
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CASE` should only return a single column, not  a tuple ("record").

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_unique_creation 
    ON junk ((CASE 
                WHEN nlevel(path) > 1 THEN subpath(path, 0, -1) 
                ELSE path 
              END), name) 
WHERE my_col IS NULL;
```

Comment: hmm, while this doesn't cause errors, it doesn't do what i'm trying to make it do... i'm trying to make an index where the subpath (or path) and name are unique... how would i do that?

Comment: @BigBug: well, that index does that - at least the combination of (sub)path and name